# Primitives and the fundamental theorem of calculus for functions with poles

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, residue-calculus, analytic-functions

I would like to integrate
$$
\int_{\Gamma_{W}}\frac{1}{\cos^2z}dz=\int_{-H}^{H}\frac{1}{\cos^2(W+iy)}idy
$$
where the contour is the vertical line between $W-iH$ and $W+iH$. Of course, we know
$$\frac{d}{dz}\tan z=\frac{1}{\cos^2z} \, ,$$
so as long as $W$ is not a zero of cosine (so that $\frac{1}{\cos^2z}$ is analytic in a neighborhood around the contour) it would seem that in this region $\tan z$ is a primitive of $\frac{1}{\cos^2z}$ so by the fundamental theorem of calculus that I can evaluate this as
$$\int_{\Gamma_{W}}\frac{1}{\cos^2z}dz=\tan(W+iH)-\tan(W-iH) \, .$$

However, if I simply evaluate the tangent at the endpoints, then there is no difference between integrating along the blue contour or the red contour below. In each case, I can draw a neighborhood around the contour, in which $\frac{1}{\cos^2z}$ is analytic. Clearly the integrals along each contour should differ by the residue of the pole between them. What simple mistake am I making?

[image: Two contours]

Comment: What are those residues? Are they non-zero? When does a meromorphic function has a primitive on its full domain ( so everywhere but the poles?)

Comment: @Conrad - As you suggest, the residues are zero. By comparison, $1/z$ has a nonzero residue, but its primitives are natural logarithms plus a constant, and the constant $2\pi i$ is the difference between natural logarithms in different branches. Are you saying that when the residue is nonzero, the primitives are on different branches? I do not know the answer to your second question.

Comment: Exactly - $1/z$ doesn't have an antiderivative on the punctured plane, only on a cut of it; similarly any meromorphic function has an antiderivative on its full domain (plane minus poles) iff all its residues are zeroes (antiderivative means circle integral zero, so doing it on a small one around a pole, so no other pole in, gives one way, explicitly computing the antiderivative gives the other way)